# Разница между датой текущей и датой из SqlLite

Tags: timestamp, sqlite, java

Создаю базу данных с таблицей parameter следущим образом:

```
db.execSQL("create table parameter (id_p integer primary key autoincrement,str text, time TIMESTAMP default (DATETIME('now', 'localtime')) not null);");
```

Мне нужно сравнить текущую дату с датой из этой самой базы данных. Разницу нужно получить в количестве дней. 
Подскажите как это можно сделать.

Comment: вы создаете не базу а таблицу. а так вы путаетесь в понятиях стоит сначала зайти на википедию почитать основы. а потом обновить вопрос, - и получить ответ

Comment: @jmu, исправила. Пойдет? Хотя и раньше было ясно, если не придираться к понятиям

Comment: Ну что опять что ли мне отвечать?!

Comment: @Мария_1 : зря вы обижаетесь. часто бывает такое что человек путается в понятиях поэтому вкладывает другой смысл в общепринятые термины. как результат - получает в ответах не то что ему надо.

p.s. субд еще укажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю. Вопрос состоит из 2-х частей:

1. Вытащить из таблицы дату
2. Сравнить эту дату с текущей и выдать количество дней.

Вытаскивается из БД запросом типа `select time from parameter`. Поскольку речь (видимо) идет об Android, то в терминах Android это будет нечто такое:

```
Cursor cursor=storage.rawQuery("select time from parameters", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   long millis=cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("time"));
   Date myDate=new Date(millis);
}
```

Далее имеем myDate в виде Java объекта Date и получаем количество дней типа:

```
int days=(myDate.getTime()-(new Date()).getTime())/86400;
```

Надеюсь, дальше уже сами сообразите что к чему.

Comment: @Barmaley, большое спасибо) постараюсь именно так сделать) ни первый раз выручаете)